# Is there a way to determine the type of edit used with onEdit in a Google Sheets Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-workspace

I need to know if a user is deleting a row, editing a cell, or pasting a bunch of cells. I keep looking through documentation and I cannot find a way to determine what the user's action is. Is there a way in to know what kind of action is used in onEdit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the installable change event listener for Sheets.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#change

It *is* possible to determine if a row was deleted by testing for the `REMOVE_ROW` change type.

It is also possible to determine whether a single cell or multiple cells were edited.  See code below.

Pasting will not insert rows or columns, so if the change type "EDIT" happened, then you can assume that rows or columns were not inserted.  I don't know of any way to manually edit multiple cells at the same time, so if the active range includes multiple cells, then it was probably a "paste."

```
function nameOfFunction(e) {
  var A1Notation,typeOfChange;

  //Install this function as a trigger for Sheets change

  typeOfChange = e.changeType;//Get the type of change that was made
  Logger.log('typeOfChange: ' + typeOfChange)
  Logger.log('typeof typeOfChange: ' + typeof typeOfChange)

  switch(typeOfChange) {
    case 'REMOVE_ROW':
      Logger.log('A row was deleted')
      break;
    case 'EDIT':
      A1Notation = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getA1Notation();
      Logger.log('A1Notation: ' + A1Notation)
      if (A1Notation.indexOf(":") === -1) {//There is NOT a colon in the A1 notation
        Logger.log('An Edit was made to a single cell')
      } else {
        Logger.log('An Edit was made to MULTIPLE cells')
      }
      break;
    case 'OTHER':
      /*  This is NOT an edit of types
        EDIT, INSERT_ROW, INSERT_COLUMN, REMOVE_ROW, REMOVE_COLUMN, INSERT_GRID, REMOVE_GRID, FORMAT
      */
      Logger.log('This is NOT an edit or a row Deletion')
      break;
    default:

  }

}
```

Comment: This did it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently possible using `onEdit()`. The most you can find from an [Edit Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit) is the old / new values of the cell. **Note: This only works if it's only one cell being edited.**

You could, for example, use `e.range` to determine the range that has been edited but it will not tell you the type of edit that has taken place.

Answer (score 0):

**What's in an Event Trigger?**

If you want to know what an event object has in it then you can do something like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
}
```

In the case of a simple onEdit() trigger this is what it contains:

```
[19-05-30 10:19:36:809 MDT] {"authMode":{},"range":{"columnStart":4,"rowStart":4,"rowEnd":4,"columnEnd":4},"source":{},"user":{"nickname":"Your Nickname","email":"Your Email"},"value":"NewValue"}
```

Comment: Yes but this doesn't tell what type of Edit the user did

Comment: In the case of an onEdit() it's either a user edit to a cell or group of cells.